# c++ using shared libraries if installed

Tags: c++

How can I conditionality load and use a shared library if it is installed, but still run without that functionality if it is not there? more specifically, can I do that without using that library as a plugin? I prefer failing during build time rather than runtime if possible.

if I build it with the library flag -lfoo, it builds. But then it fails to run it libfoo.so.2 is not installed in the target system. But if I don't add the library flag it fails in linking.

here is some code snipets for better picture.

myAdapter.cpp

```
#include "newlib/foo.h" //this is from the shared library
...

bool myAdapter::isAvailable()
{
  handle_ = dlopen("libfoo.so.2", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (!handle_)
  {
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}

...

bool myAdapter::init()
{  
  if (!isAvailable())
  {
    return false;
  }

  isInitilized = false;
  isConnected = false;
  if (!fooInit()) // shared library function
  {
    fooCleanup(); //shared library function
    return false;
  }

  // these are my private functions but they call shared library functions.
  if (!createUserParams_() || !setCallbacks_() || !createContext_() || !connect_())
  {
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}
...
```

myApp.cpp

```
#include "myAdapter.h"
...
int main()
{
...
foo = new myAdapter();
if (!foo.init())
{
cout << "Foo function is not available;
isFooAvailable = false;
}
}

...

}
```

Comment: `prefer failing during build time rather than runtime if possible. if I build it with the library flag -lfoo, it builds. But then it fails to run it libfoo.so.2 is not installed in the target system. ` how should it fail while building if you don’t know if the library is installed on the target system?

Comment: I already added isAvailable() function in init(). So, it won't go any further at runtime. I just wanted to check as much as possible during the build time.

Comment: can't edit my answer anymore, so I add here. I would like to check if I am using the library APIs correctly. Also, the shared library has bunch of internal structs and enums such as for error codes etc. I also would like to leverage those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a shared library delay loaded on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403848/how-to-make-a-shared-library-delay-loaded-on-linux). That thread mentions a helper script project to generate stubs for the library functions which will load the library on first access - https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so

Answer (score 2):

First, remove any linkage you have to libfoo.a, libfoo.sa, or any `-lfoo` parameter in your build.  Everything is to be dynamically loaded.

Second, after `dlopen` succeeds, you need to get the address, via `dlsym`, of all the functions you need to use - and call through into those.

Third, instead of making a direct call to your functions, you call through to them via the pointer you loaded via dlsym.

Finally, your isAvailable has a side effect (loading the library) and will re-attempt every time. You just need to load the library once.

Here's an improved version of your code. I made some hypothetical assumptions of what your params to those library functions would be. Change it to meet your needs:

```
class myAdapter
{
    void* handle_;

    typedef bool (*CREATE_USER_PARAMS)(UserParams*);
    typedef int (*CONNECT)(int);

    CREATE_USER_PARAMS createUserParams_;
    CONNECT connect_; 

    myAdapter() : 
        handle_(),
        createUserParams_(),
        connect_()
    {
       handle_ = dlopen("libfoo.so.2", RTLD_NOW);
       if (handle_)
       {
           createUserParams = (CREATE_USER_PARAMS)dlsym(handle_, "createUserParams");
           connect_ = (CONNECT)dlsym(handle_, "connect");
           if (!createUserParams_ || !connect_)
           {
              // error
              dlclose(handle_);
              handle_ = nullptr;
              connect = nullptr_;
              createUserParams_ = nullptr;
           }
       }
    }  

    ~myAdapter()
    {
       if (handle_) 
       {
           dlclose(handle_);
           handle = nullptr;
       }
    }

    bool createUserParams(UserParams* params)
    {
        if (createUserParams_ != nullptr)
        {
            return createUserParams_(params);
        }
        else
        {
           return false;
        }
    }

    int connect(int sock)
    {
        if (connect_ != nullptr)
        {
            return (connect_(sock));
        }
        else
        {
           return -1;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I appreciate it. But this is as mentioned in my question, using the shared library as a plugin. and this will fail on runtime if any of the API signatures changes, for example, if they change the init to return int instead of bool, etc. I would like to catch those errors during build time if possible. Maybe with some linking flags etc. Again, I don't know if this is possible, that is why I am asking. thanks again.